# How do I link Office 365 service to existing Azure AD?

Tags: microsoft-office-365, entra-id, microsoft-office

I want to buy a new Office 365 offering but I do not want it to use its own Azure AD, instead I want it to use the Azure AD tenant that I specify.

Is this done at Office 365 creation time or can be done later ?

Comment: It sounds like you want to just add an M365 subscription to an existing Azure AD tenant OR create an Azure AD B2B relationship between the two.

Answer (score 1):

This should be done during initial signup, but not afterwards.

> If you're part of an organization that has an Azure subscription, you can create Microsoft 365 subscriptions for users in your existing Azure Active Directory (Azure AD). Sign up for Microsoft 365 using an account that has Global Admin or Billing Admin permissions in your Azure Active Directory tenant

You can find more details here: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cost-management-billing/manage/azure-account-for-microsoft-365-subscription